# how to know the original website after a 301 redirection

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-headers

I have multiple old websites: `https//website-a.com`, `https//website-b.com`, `https//website-c.com`...

I want to permanently redirect all the traffic to one of my new websites `https://www.my-new-website-a.com` or `https://www.my-new-website-b.com` and display a message depending on the website originally asked.

I have the full list of redirects with exact matches, for example:

```
https//website-a.com/abc => https://www.my-new-website-a.com/xyz
https//website-a.com/def => https://www.my-new-website-b.com/ghi
https//website-a.com/jkl => https://www.my-new-website-a.com
```

My old domains are now pointing to a nginx app.

I tried to setup a 301 redirection with nginx and adding a header. The header is only visible on the 301 requests, but not on the final destination.

```
http {
  server {
    listen <%= ENV['PORT'] %>;
    server_name MyServer;
    
    location / {
        return 301 http://www.my-new-website.com;
        add_header X-Redirected-From WebsiteA;
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried to set a cookie with Nginx but without any success:

```
add_header Set-Cookie "origin_website=website_a; Path=/; Domain=my-new-website.com; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2023 12:00:00 GMT;";
        proxy_cookie_domain website-a.com my-new-website.com;
```

I have thousands of urls to redirect, for SEO reasons, I don't want to add a "source" query parameter on the final path.

I have the full control on all the applications. The new website is running on Nuxt.js